# Which C++20 standard library containers have a .at member access function?

Tags: c++, c++20

Which C++20 standard library containers have a `.at` function?  For example, at least `std::map`, `std::unordered_map` and `std::vector` do.  What others are there?

Is there some way to work this out without going through the 2000 page standard by hand?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Usually, you select a container based on your needs, then figure out how to access its members. Why do you need that information?

Comment: @kebs: I'm designing a new member access function for the standard containers (that returns a pointer rather than a reference, and that returns nullptr rather than throws) and I want to apply it to all the standard containers that currently provide `.at`

Comment: You use cppreference for this. It's also questionable to have something working only specifically for standard library types. Why not any other type?

Comment: If it's general, shouldn't returning `nullptr` if there is no `at()` enough? Or `static_assert()` it.

Comment: @PasserBy: Here is a live link to my current draft if you're interested: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ovHNnx9Tdzzlqtarjobawdjd-g0bXDYHHCHHruJsock/edit?usp=sharing  Feel free to email me if you want to discuss.

Comment: @LouisGo: See link in previous comment.

Comment: This link contains a comparison of the different container types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: Your template function might be constrained by presence of `.at` method.

Comment: @Jarod42: You mean a function template?  There are no function templates in play here?  I don't understand sorry.

Comment: How else do you apply the new function to all containers without using a template? You could do it manually. By constraining you could say every class which is a `Container` (named requirement https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) and has an `at` member function. Constraining can be done with SFINAE (and the metafunctions using it, e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) or with concepts.

Comment: Perhaps `SequenceContainer` is, what you actually want: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer

Comment: @Sebastian `map` isn't a *SequenceContainer*, and not all *AssociativeContainer*s have `at`

Comment: @Sebastian: Sorry I don't understand, the specification is given in the paper.  See the above google doc link in previous comment.

Comment: Ah, okay, it is for (official) extension of the standard libraries instead of in a company/private repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up grepping libstdc++ include directory for `\bat(` and that has given me:

```
std::basic_string
std::basic_string_view
std::array
std::vector
std::vector<bool>
std::unordered_map
std::map
std::dequeue
```

I'm not sure if this is exhaustive.

There is also `rope` and `vstring` but I don't think these are standard.

Comment: From memory, `rope` was part of the STL, but was never adopted as part of the C++ standard library.  Don't know about `vstring`.

Answer (score 3):

From comments, it seems you want something like:

```
template <typename Container, typename T>
typename Container::pointer my_at(Container&, const T&)
requires (requires(Container c, const T& key) { c.at(key); })
{
   // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PEYqj4q7W)

Comment: I'd be tempted to split this into `requires(Container c, Container::size_type index) { c.at(index); }` and `requires(Container c, T && key) { c.find(key); }`

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting and all but didn't really answer my question.  I asked for a list of containers that support .at. :)  For context see https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ovHNnx9Tdzzlqtarjobawdjd-g0bXDYHHCHHruJsock/edit?usp=sharing  It's ok, I've figured it out now I think (by grepping libstdc++ headers).

Comment: Indeed, if it is for a paper, my answer doesn't fit. As a note, you should use [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) instead of `&` for generic code (to handle evil `operator&`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a pointer is the appropriate type to return for this operation, instead it should be an iterator. At which point the definition splits into two cases:

Random access containers:

```
iterator at_(size_type index) noexcept { return index < size() ? begin() + index : end(); }
const_iterator at_(size_type index) const noexcept { return index < size() ? begin() + index : end(); }
```

`map` and `unordered_map`:

```
template<typename T>
iterator at_(T && key) noexcept { return find(std::forward<T>(key)); }
template<typename T>
const_iterator at_(T && key) const noexcept { return find(std::forward<T>(key)); }
```

And then rather than testing against `nullptr`, you test against the container's `end()`.

It's also a reasonable question as to whether (unordered_)map needs an alias for an existing member to match your nomenclature

Comment: Iterators don't work with declaration if statements, because they are not convertible to bool.  `if (auto p = m.at_ptr(k)) f(*p) else g();`.  See the example in the paper.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos `if` has had an optional *init-statement* since C++17. `if (auto it = m.at_(k); it != m.end())`

Comment: I know that. Even without init-statement you can write today `auto it = m.find(k); if (it != m.end()) f(it->second) else g();`, but we feel that `if (T* p = m.at_ptr(k)) f(*p) else g();` is more readable and ergonomic.